# How to resize vw units

Tags: css, accessibility

Is it possible to make viewport units like vw, vh and vmin scale with the browser font resize?

On windows it's <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>. I need the benefit of these units but according to [wcag 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#visual-audio-contrast-scale) the text must be scalable by 200%.

Comment: No. The answer is no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i enlarge wesite font-size when used with vw unit for WCAG (accessibility) propeses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902430/how-can-i-enlarge-wesite-font-size-when-used-with-vw-unit-for-wcag-accessibilit)